# Monero withdrawn from Kraken but not showing in my Ledger Nano S hardware wallet via Monero GUI wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization, transaction-confirmation, ledger

On Thursday evening (BST) I withdrew some Monero from Kraken online exchange to the wallet address generated by setting up a Ledge Nano S Hardware wallet in the Monero Gui wallet (v0.16.0.2(Qt 5.12.2)  on my laptop. I had to disable my anti-virus to get the above to work.
According to Kraken the withdraw went through fine.
I have tried changing the wallet restore height to 2100000 to resolve the below issues. The laptop has remained on and as far as i can tell connected to the internet at all times.
The Monero GUI Wallet has been rotating between the below states over the last 5 days, I feel like I am getting nowhere fast >

- Straight after withdrawal
  •   Network status synchronising
  •   Waiting for Daemon to sync
  •   Syncing
- 24 July 09.58am
  •   Network status synchronising
  •   Daemon is synchronised
  •   Wallet blocks remaining 19884
- 26th July 10.49am
  •   Network status synchronising
  •   Daemon is synchronised
  •   Wallet blocks remaining 47413
- 26th July 14.56
  •   Network status Connected
  •   Daemon is synchronised (2150598)
  •   Waiting for daemon to sync
- 26th July 18:47
  •   Network status Connected
  •   Daemon is synchronised
  •   Wallet blocks remaining 45604
- 26th July 23:14
  •   Network status Synchronizing
  •   Daemon blocks remaining (2150932)
  •   Waiting for daemon to sync
- 27th July 16:08
  •   Network status Synchronizing
  •   Daemon is synchronised
  •   Wallet blocks remaining 42403
- 27th July 22:07
  •   Network status Synchronizing
  •   Daemon is synchronised
  •   Wallet blocks remaining 41545

And now back to
•   Network status synchronising
•   Waiting for Daemon to sync
•   Daemon blocks remaining 2152090

I am worried now as I am new to crypto currency and don’t know where my withdrawal is or how I can get it transferred to my wallet.
Can anyone offer any advice on how I might be able to find my Monero?
Is my wallet address portable? i.e. can I set up Monero GUI Wallet again on another computer and point it to the same hardware wallet address?
Am I going to have to go through the whole process again of installing Monero etc? If so do I need to export anything from my existing install?

Comment: Would you mind making a thread on r/monerosupport? Reddit is a better avenue to provide support.

Comment: Thanks for replying to me. I actually finally managed to get the wallet to sync earlier and can now see the monero. However I have a couple of questions I'll move to Reddit, thanks again!

Comment: All right, looking forward to your questions!